# Would using seafood stock instead of chicken broth/stock work in a butternut squash soup?

Tags: substitutions, stock, broth, squash

I'm trying to make a butternut squash bisque, specifically, which by its least-strict definition involves a seafood stock/broth.

All the recipes I've found are for butternut squash soup, which is not as fun to make or talk about.

My concern is that the fishiness of the seafood broth/stock will overpower the butternuttiness, or make it taste flat-out disgusting.

I'm using [Chef John's](http://foodwishes.blogspot.com/2015/09/roasted-butternut-squash-soup-legend-of.html) recipe for this.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR**

As long as you get the *balance* right anything that's tasty separately can be mixed together and still be tasty.

What I would do is to make the butternut squash soup first without any stock, set aside one bowl of said soup and then little by little add the shrimp/lobster stock into the kettle until just right to your taste-buds.  Then add the separate bowl back into the kettle.

**Why?** Your taste-buds will have gotten gradually used to the shrimp/lobster stock and the final product will be *slightly* over the top, so adding the bowl back in will make it just right for your guests.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Fishing vor votes, are we? Here you go... (I *do* question your statement of "anything that's tasty seperately can be mixed together and still be tasty". You are skirting some really *grey* areas - It would need a kitchen genius to combine pickeled herring and chocolate, for example. You are setting the bar too high for the average cook on this site.)  The hint about adapting taste buds is very good though.

Comment: Pickled herring, a bit of honey and a sprinkling of bitter cocoa good enough for your challenge? @Stephie That should result in a sweet&sour with a slight tang of bittery and should come close to how the [Danes eat their herring](http://www.copenhagenet.dk/CPH-Map/CPH-Recipes-5-11-Marinated-Herring.asp)...  **:P ;-)**